# DRF nested serializer issue on create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a User model and a phone model the phone model has a foreign key relation with the user model I read the docs on NestedSerializers and tried it to no avail.

**The model**

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(
        _("phone number"), max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)
    otp = IntegerRangeField(min_value=6, max_value=6, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    phone = models.ForeignKey(
            Phone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userphone", blank=False, null=True)
```

**this is my serializers.py file**

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # opt = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ['phone']


    class RegisterSerializerBase(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        phone = PhoneSerializer(allow_null=True)
        # otp = PhoneSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        email = serializers.EmailField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    
        password = serializers.CharField(
            write_only=True, re

quired=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'password', 'password2',
                  'phone',)
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},
                        'password2': {'write_only': True},
                        'firstname': {'required': True},
                        'lastname': {'required': True},
                        }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phones = validated_data.pop('phone')
        instance = User.objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            firstname=validated_data['firstname'],
            lastname=validated_data['lastname'],
            is_active='True',
            type=User.TYPES.OWNER,
        )
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        for phone in phones:
            Phone.objects.create(instance=instance, **phone)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

when I go the the Browsable API and create a user with the credentials an **error comes up saying**

```
django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

Comment: show your models, what is related_name that you have used ?

Comment: i edited it in check it out

Comment: You have not understood the nested serializers, everything you are doing is opposite of how it should be done.  There should be no phone in user models but user in phone models. Read the docs again and try to understand.  Now this is your code **Phone.objects.create(instance=instance, **phone)** during phone creation you are passing instance which is user but in your model, phone model has no user.

Comment: that was the first thing I tried but it didn't work for me the error is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps you -

Models -
User model is already defined.

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    user = models.Foerienkey(User, related_name="abc")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)
```

Serializer -

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CurrentUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    abc = phoneserializer(many=True, required=False)
    ## define phone serializer before currentuser serializer
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'id', 'abc')
```

Views -

##user create method

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
        phones = validated_data.pop('recievedPhoneDataArray')
        instance = User.objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            firstname=validated_data['firstname'],
            lastname=validated_data['lastname'],
            is_active='True',
            type=User.TYPES.OWNER,
        )
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        for phone in phones:
            Phone.objects.create(user=instance, **phone)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

You will have to extend the registeruserserializer from rest frameowrk. may be.

Comment: didn't work bro thanks tho, it's still the same error

Comment: phones = validated_data.pop('recievedPhoneDataArray')  the recievedPhoneDataArray should be changed with abc or the related name field in general

Comment: whatever is related name

Comment: did it but not working but as i understand i don't think the post data/div should be like `email 
'kkkv2@gk.com'
firstname 
'kkkkgfv2'
lastname 
'aschalewv2'
password 
'kalebcool1234'
password2 
'kalebcool1234'
userphone.phone 
'+251956566512'` right or is this correct?

Comment: i thought the post data would be `userphone.user.somthn`

Comment: ok tell me, you are trying to add multiple phone numbers  of a user when creating a user or something else ?

Comment: yes smthn like that, after the initial register they can link many numbers to their account

Comment: and how do you register, using rest-auth registration or what  ?

Comment: custom, the above code is the registration serializer

Comment: found solution?

Comment: nope, i really appreciate your efforts to help though.

Comment: i just dropped the idea of 1 person having multiple numbers.